# behavior of this, inside a function, in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made some search around but wasn't able to find the exact answer for:

```
this.age = 20;

var getAge = function () {
    return this.age;
};

var person = {
    age: 30,
    getAge: getAge
};

console.log(this.age); // 20
console.log(getAge()); // undefined
console.log(person.getAge()); // 30
```

Why, in Node.js, the "this", when used inside the getAge function in the code, is undefined, if it is actually defined?

Considering only the language, it should work?

I know that:

```
console.log(this === exports);
console.log(this === module.exports);
```

Notice that in Chrome, it works and the getAge(), when executed, return 20.

Comment: Try doing `var self = this;` at the top of your function, and then have getAge() return self.age instead. It's a common workaround for "this" weirdness in JS.

Comment: @Quentin I think there's a node specificity here. `this` isn't the root object.

Comment: @Quentin My question was regarding the behavior of "this", inside a function, in Node.js, not the language. The question that you pointed is far more broad...

Comment: Thanks guys, I know how to solve it, I just want to understand the exact behavior of "this", inside a function in Node.js in that situation.

Comment: @apsillers The same code in a browser wouldn't log undefined here.

Comment: @apsillers that works in the browser, did not work in Node.js, just wondering to know more details around it.

Comment: @RodrigoBranas `Why, in Node.js, the "this", when used inside the getAge function in the code, is undefined, if it is actually defined?` actually `this.age` is. but still `this` has a defined value

Comment: @AdnanUmer I did not get your point...

Comment: It seems the same behavior when the Strict Mode is used, when "this" is set to undefined inside functions to avoid mistakes when using constructor function without new